# Drywall texture

Tags: drywall

I was at this restaurant the other day and came across these walls that looks too have wallpaper on them by the first glance but then I came to realize that it was some type of textured drywall mud or what it looks to be like. I was wondering if anyone has seen this before ?[image]

Comment: Would not say textured more like a badly done  patch job.

Comment: Looks like a knockdown texture to me - a thick one.  It is basically a skim coat of mud that almost completely covers the wall that is trowled flat while it is still wet.

Comment: Google “old world” drywall finish.

Comment: Looks like a damaged skim coat to me, like someone stuck something to the wall and peeled it off, taking the skim with it.